# Public IP still the same as previously when used with proxy

Tags: networking, proxy

I am trying to use a proxy from https://www.proxynova.com/proxy-server-list/country-kr/.

I picked one: 222.111.36.25, port 80. It's listed as an elite proxy, with 94% uptime.

I have already added a proxy address and port no from proxynova.com to my Mac 10.11's System Preferences > Network > Advanced Settings > Proxy > Web Proxy (HTTP). I have clicked on "Apply".

I used Safari 11.1 to check my IP on google and whatsmyip.com. Why hasn't my public IP changed?

Answer (score 0):

Safari has it's own proxy settings. Go into preferences/advanced/proxy and configure as necessary.